# What's the difference between DeclaredMembers from TypeInfo and GetMembers from Type?

Tags: c#, .net

below is some source code:

```
public abstract class Type : MemberInfo, _Type, IReflect {
   public MemberInfo[] GetMembers();
   public MethodInfo[] GetMethods();
   public FieldInfo[] GetFields();
   public PropertyInfo[] GetProperties();
   public ConstructorInfo[] GetConstructors();
   ...
}

public abstract class TypeInfo : Type, IReflectableType {
   public virtual IEnumerable<MemberInfo> DeclaredMembers { get; }
   public virtual IEnumerable<MethodInfo> DeclaredMethods { get; }
   public virtual IEnumerable<FieldInfo> DeclaredFields { get; }
   public virtual IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> DeclaredProperties { get; }
   public virtual IEnumerable<ConstructorInfo> DeclaredConstructors { get; }
   ...
}
```

My question is, what's the difference betweet using GetXXX in Type and its counterpart DeclaredXXX in TypeInfo? They looks identical, and if you already have a batch in `Type`, why we still another batch in `TypeInfo` considering `TypeInfo` inherits from `Type`?

Comment: You can look in [sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/typeinfo.cs,f4c48ee604408077) to see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `DeclaredOnly` BindingFlags used in the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/typeinfo.cs,1bb00b5b731c6a0d) it seems only members that are "declared at the level of the supplied type's hierarchy" are considered. So inherited members are not considered.

This proves that it's true:

```
void Main()
{
    TypeInfo fooType = typeof(Foo).GetTypeInfo();
    Console.WriteLine("Declared properties");
    foreach(var m in fooType.DeclaredProperties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Name);
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Properties");
    foreach (var m in fooType.GetProperties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Name);
    }
}

public class Foo: Bah
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
public class Bah
{
    public int Id{get;set;} 
}
```

This prints:

```
Declared properties
Name

Properties
Name
Id
```